# Create a DataFrame in Python from BeautifulSoup extract

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I am able to extract data , a list of words from the web using BeautifulSoup. The data is collected in the component synonyms[i].text. However when I want to convert the data extracted into a dataframe I get the words split into letters rather than in complete words. How do I convert the data into a proper list of words in a proper dataframe i.e., where a word like 'analyse' is in the data frame as 'analyse' and not split as 'a','n','a','l','y','s','e' ?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
page = requests.get("https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/guard.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')


keyword = "guard"

synonyms = soup.select('.relatedwords')
for i in range(0, 1):
              print ('synonyms section ' + str(i + 1))
              print pd.DataFrame((list(synonyms[i].text)))

#Output that I need to convert into a DataFrame
synonyms section 1

fighter
trooper
warrior
serviceman

#The Output I am getting in the list
```

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow. 
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.

Comment: You also need to specify your problem.  Show inputs and desired output, for starters.  There's no reason to involve `requests` and `BeautifulSoup` in your posting, as they are not part of your question.  Simply hard-code a sample list for `synonyms and ask your question from there.

Comment: @Prune. I am extracting the data using beautifulsoup. But I will add a hard coded list if that makes it easier. Thanks for helping me with my question framing.

Comment: @Prune. I have updated my question further. Thanks for helping me with framing my question.

Comment: I vote for reopen, because answer was edited/ improved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need strip for remove first and last `\n` and then split for list of words:

```
for i in range(0, 1):
    print ('synonyms section ' + str(i + 1))
    print (pd.DataFrame({'text': synonyms[i].text.strip().split()}))
    
          text
0     guardian
1    custodian
2       warden
3       keeper
4       sentry
..         ...
211    soldier
212       park
213     ranger
214       more
215          ❯

[216 rows x 1 columns]
```

If need all values to DataFrame use `extend` method for add lists to `L` list and then call DataFrame constructor outside loop:

```
L = []
for i, syno in enumerate(synonyms):
    print ('synonyms section ' + str(i + 1))
    L.extend(syno.text.strip().split())

df = pd.DataFrame({'text':L})
print(df)
           text
0      guardian
1     custodian
2        warden
3        keeper
4        sentry
        ...
7667  Languages
7668          g
7669         gu
7670        gua
7671       guar

[7672 rows x 1 columns]
```

Comment: Thank you so much @jezrael ! That resolved my query.

Answer (score 2):

keep the word in list.

```
syno_list = list()
for i, syno in enumerate(synonyms):
    print ('synonyms section ' + str(i + 1))
    word_list = syno.text.strip().split()
    syno_list.append(word_list)
    print(word_list)
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me with this @Ferris.